# Software to store my password on a crypted file and access it through another password

Tags: windows, encryption, passwords

I'm looking for a software that allows me to store some passwords in something like "a text file", access it through a password, read my passwords if required and close it again.

I want something really straightforward, double click on file, right click "Add new password", add password, description and close.

The file must be really secure, I'll store all my passwords there.
I know about some command line solutions but I want my setup to be really fast on reading.

Do someone know if such a software exist and can point me in the correct direction? I would like to find it freeware, but I'm ok with some low cost tools too.

Comment: Look at solutions like `1Pass` and `LastPass`

Comment: TrueCrypt would be a good choice for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do someone know if such a software exist and can point me in the correct direction?

prodoct recommendation are off-topic on SuperUser, but: It exists.

Search on the term **eWallet**.

Comment: Thanks, nice recommendation. Well because I don't know if such a software exist, I just would like to know it and its name. I hoped for a freeware solution but I can't find one really.

Comment: That is why I named the term for it. You can find dozens of useful programs out there, but I avoided naming a specific one. (Both because it would show personal bias, and because what works today may not be there next month. But knowing the term to search for will always help).

Comment: AHHHHH That's the term, that's really **much more helpful**! I thought it was a name of the software. Great, I'll look over the web for it, thanks again!.

Comment: I found an "aWallet" on my android phone which is great, that "eWallet" term was really helpful